# Visual Studio 2008 charset converting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, character-encoding, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, copy and paste after then charset changes. (HTML source and code behind)

Original letters (Turkish): ğüşiöç, pasted chars: Ã„Å¸ÃƒÂ¼Ã…Å¸iÃƒÂ¶ÃƒÂ§.

How do I fix?

Comment: Use `System.Text.GetEncoding`. Search for it or read [THIS.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the file has no BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and HTML doesn't contain charset metadata. So browser interprets the content as latin-1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

You should specify charset:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
```

And optionally save file in UTF-8 with signature:
[image]

See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#detail